# How to get values on server side in Spring ROO?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am having a question regarding Spring ROO. Although this is not a good question to ask still as i am facing some issue.

I have created Spring ROO application using below link in Eclipse

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html

After putting some efforts i was able to see the application output as desired then a doubt came to mind that how i will print value from browser to Controller  i.e. client to server side (System.out.println("")).

I have tried many solution but nothing seems to be working. So can some one tell me how will i do it.

Just to summarize the thing i want value from textfield etc in my .java file using above Spring ROO project.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo just creates a Spring Web MVC application.

In your question I found that you need some architectural concepts about Spring Web MVC and Web applications that you must know to start developing application.

Try to read some tutorials and post ([this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/) looks good) before start to develop your application.

Good luck!
Chema.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Chema  I have tried that way also Example:- @RequestMapping(value = "/bases")
 public void gettingData(@RequestParam ("name") String name) {
  System.out.println("Name = "+name);
 }            But still not working